# How to do versioning of a graph database like neo4j

Tags: neo4j, database-migration

I started to use [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org) with its [Java API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html?_ga=1.251312197.297593769.1402608042) to store and retrieve graph oriented data.

Now I came to a point where I have to add a label, a constraint or remove a node attribute.

Using relational databases I used [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) to migrate a database to the next version.

What would be the best way to migrate a neo4j database? Are there any libraries supporting this?

I use neo4j 2

Comment: not being aware of a ready to go solution for this. However since there is no schema, you don't need to change it. For data migration you could most likely use a set of Cypher statements doing the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool out there being worked on, which copies the concepts of liquibase called [Liquigraph](http://liquigraph.github.io/). The source github page here: https://github.com/liquigraph/liquigraph.

Although the tool is still quite young the author is very receptive to feedback and is actively working on the tool.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not yet.

I'm in [discussion](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/777) with Axel Fontaine of [FlyWayDB](http://flywaydb.org/) to add support for Neo4j.

As stefan said, You can use Cypher statements to migrate data.

Please note that you might have to batch operations if there is a lot of data in your database.

e.g. batching in 100k chunks to migrate a type property to a Label.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.type) AND n.type = "User"
WITH n
LIMIT 100000
SET n:User
REMOVE n.type
```